# sql split string by space into table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I looking for a function like regexp_split_to_table, but our db is version 8.2.9, so it doesn't have it. I'm really only splitting on a space, so a string like

> how now brown cow

would return

```
+------+
|Column|
+------+
|how   | 
|now   | 
|brown | 
|cow   |
+------+
```

is there a simple function that can handle this, or something I have to write myself?

Comment: regexp_split_to_table was introduced in 8.3, so you were just shy of having the feature :- (

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can split an array to a resultset by using the unnest function, and you can turn a string literal into an array by using the string_to_array function.  Combine both and you get this:

```
alvherre=# select unnest(string_to_array('the quick lazy fox', ' '));
 unnest 
--------
 the
 quick
 lazy
 fox
(4 filas)
```

Since 8.2 does not have UNNEST, you can write it in PostgreSQL like this:

```
create or replace function unnest(anyarray) returns setof anyelement
language sql as $$
   select $1[i] from generate_series(array_lower($1, 1),
                                     array_upper($1, 1)) as i;
$$;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to `RETURNS SET` or `RETURNS TABLE` yourself.

**Updated answer:** using PL/pgSQL:

```
pg=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_to_rows(text) RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$ 
  DECLARE
    elems text[];      
  BEGIN
    elems := string_to_array($1, ' ');
    FOR i IN array_lower(elems, 1) .. array_upper(elems, 1) LOOP
      RETURN NEXT elems[i];
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE FUNCTION

pg=> SELECT "Column" FROM string_to_rows('how now brown cow') d("Column");
 Column 
--------
 how
 now
 brown
 cow
(4 rows)
```

**Original answer:** using PL/perl:

```
pg=> CREATE LANGUAGE plperl; 
CREATE LANGUAGE

pg=> CREATE FUNCTION psplit_to_rows(text) RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS $$
pg$>   for my $t (split ' ', $_[0]) { return_next $t; }
pg$>   undef;
pg$> $$ LANGUAGE plperl;
CREATE FUNCTION

pg=> SELECT "Column" FROM psplit_to_rows('how now brown cow') d("Column");
 Column 
--------
 how
 now
 brown
 cow
(4 rows)
```

Obviously you can extend this to handle a delimiter of your choosing, etc.  (Note, I'm not sure if you really wanted that column named "Column", requiring identifier quoting to avoid keyword clash, but, there you are.)

Comment: I don't have plperl to work with, can this easily be done w/ plpgsql?

Comment: @pilcrow,  Your function works great,  but I'm having a problem when I try to execute a query like [select string_to_rows(column) from table].

Keeps giving me the error:
ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set.

Looking around online I see I need to call like [select * from string_to_rows(text)].

Is it possible to call this function and pass in a set?
ie [select * from string_to_rows(select col from table)].

Comment: @veilig, you're trying to put a set or table into a SQL scalar context.  A separate question, showing us what data you're starting with and what result set you want, is, I think, appropriate.