# How to select multiple row in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, resultset

I can give a result set consisting of a single value, say `1`, as follows:

```
SELECT 1 as column;
```

and it gives me the result set:

```
column
------
  1
```

But I have a list of such values represented as a string `(1, 4, 7, ...)` and I need to produce the following result set:

```
column
------
  1
  4
  7
  .
  .
  .
```

I tried `SELECT * FROM (1, 4, 7)` but it didn't work. I also tried to `SELECT 1, 4, 7` but it produces the following result set:

```
col1   col2    col3
 1       4      7
```

Which was not what I was looking for.

Comment: You need to look at the `String split` or `union`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If those are constant values, you can use the `values` clause:

```
select * 
from (
   values (1), (4), (7)
) as t(id);
```

If your values are inside a string literal, you can use this:

```
select *
from unnest(string_to_array('1,2,3,4', ',')) as id;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `unnest` it as an [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 4, 7])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) To get what you want.But if this is the sting as `1,4,7` comma seprated then you need to use the `regexp_split_to_table` function. [Mentioned here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986491/sql-split-string-by-space-into-table-in-postgresql)

```
Select 1
UNION
select 4
UNION
select 7
```

Comment: Your links are for SQL Server. Postgres already has everything built in to split a string into an array or even create a table of it.