# Replace values in array column with related values from another table

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

In my database I have a table `relations` with a column `relation_ids` containing the IDs of users (`user_id`). This takes the form of an array with many IDs possible, e.g.:

```
{111,112,156,4465}
```

I have another table `names` containing information on users such as `user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name` etc.

I would like to create an SQL query to return all rows from `relations` with all columns, but append the array column `relation_ids` with `first_name` from the `names` table substituted for IDs.

Is it possible as some kind of subquery?

Comment: Part of your question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986491/sql-split-string-by-space-into-table-in-postgresql

It would be helpful to see sample data and a desired result set.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to preserve the order in the array - first names listed in the same order as IDs in the original `relation_ids`.

I suggest an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) over a correlated subquery with `unnest()` and `WITH ORDINALITY`, joined to the `names` table, like:

```sql
SELECT r.*
     , ARRAY (
          SELECT n.first_name
          FROM   unnest(r.relation_ids) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(user_id, ord)
          JOIN   names n ON n.user_id = a.user_id
          ORDER  BY a.ord
          )  AS first_names
FROM   relations r;
```

This query preserves *all* rows from `relations` in any case.

Corner cases to note:

1. A `NULL` value in `relation_ids` (for the whole column) is translated to an empty array. (Same as empty array in the source.)
2. `NULL` *elements* are silently dropped from the array.

You might want to define desired behavior if those corner cases are possible ...

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y9Z27TkW)

Related:

- [LEFT OUTER JOIN on array column with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589773/left-outer-join-on-array-column-with-multiple-values/28598658#28598658)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Considered a normalized db design:

- [Can PostgreSQL array be optimized for join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156345/can-postgresql-array-be-optimized-for-join/38160897#38160897)

Comment: Can you suggest something that would work for athena queries? I tried running the same query in athena but it gave the error


no viable alternative at input '(array ( select' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 783d65ea-d9dd-4cbf-8d9f-8f9ff6e32eab; proxy: null)

Comment: This answer is for PostgreSQL. You might ask Amazon about their product Athena.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all the columns and rows from Relations with first_name appended from the Names table.

```
Select Relations.relation_ids, Names.user_id, Names.first_name From Relations
Inner Join Names On Relations.user_id=Names.user_id
```

Comment: I get the following error:
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb = text
LINE 2: ...er Join Names On Relations.user_id=Names.....
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.