# PostgreSQL - Replace IDs inside array with values from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with the following structure:

entities

- id (int),
- name (text)

activity_status

- id (int)
- is_active (boolean)
- entities_ids (int[])

the activity status table contains only two records, with activity of True and False respectively, and the entities_ids is an array of entities that are either active or not, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM activity_status
```

Query result:

```
1  True   [1, 5, 20, 66]
2  False  [15, 77, 30]
```

I need to create a `SELECT` statement to get the active entities' names from these tables instead of the IDs.

Comment: I would go with third table, because you have M:N (many to many) model. And then you just inner join the tables.

Comment: I am only able to query the data, not permitted to modify or create further tables.

Comment: Ah I see.. In this case check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259414/replace-values-in-array-column-with-related-values-from-another-table

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I am looking for. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with active_entities as (
select s.activity, s.entities_ids, ARRAY(select e.name from unnest(s.entities_ids)  WITH ORDINALITY AS a(entity_id, ord) 
             join entities e on e.id = a.entity_id
                  )  as full_name
 from activity_status s
where s.activity = TRUE)

select entities from active_entities ae, unnest(ae.full_name) as entities
```